# How to pass data from 1 view holder to other view holder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `recycler view` that contains 2 `view holders`.

One is for Header, and one for other items.

The second view holder has checkbox in each row. When user clicks on checkbox, i want to update a counter on `header's view holder.`

I tried calling `HeaderViewHolder`from `ListViewHolder`, but its crashing with `cannot be cast to` message.

Is there any way i can pass data from 1 view holder to other.

Comment: You can use the main viewholder for the activity or fragment which contains your header and recyclerview to communicate between the two (list and header) viewholders.

Comment: @farhanjk : Thanks, any example to achieve this?

Comment: MainViewModel (create instances of ListViewModel and HeaderViewModel as properties of this viewModel). Then you can say something like `mainViewModel.header.counter = mainViewModel.list.whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can save you `HeaderViewHolder` instance and counter inside Adapter.

```
private HeaderViewHolder headerHolder;
private int counter = 0;
```

2. Initialize `headerHolder` inside `onBindViewHolder` method and set `OnClickListener` for checkbox.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
    }
    if (holder instanceof ListViewHolder) {
        // set listener and don't forget to call "counter++"
        // and "headerHolder.setTitle("title you want")" inside it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the `counter` in the `model/pojo` and then `notifyItemChanged(position)`

```
 headerModel.setCounter(updatedCounter);
 notifyItemChanged(headerPosition); // ideally should be 0
```